# inversion : dut-il pousser

Tags: grammaire

Voici un passage d'un récit que j'ai donné à mes élèves. Il provient du personnel à l'atelier Paré au Québec.

Il y a une phrase dont j'ai des difficultés à déterminer le sens :

> Selon nos compatriotes anglophones, il y avait jadis au pays un ramancheur – un bonesetter – expert dans l’art de masser les muscles endoloris et de replacer les os égarés par accident. De village en village, **ce chiropraticien avant l’heure venait au secours des mal en point, transportant dans sa mallette quelques onguents bienfaisants, avec pour tout instrument ses mains agiles déterminées à soigner, le patient dut-il pousser des cris de cochon égorgé.**

- Pourquoi « avant l'heure » ? Qu'est-ce que ça veut dire ici ? Avant quelle heure ?
- Quelle est la fonction de l'inversion dans *dut-il* ici ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out after reasoning about it...

- *avant l'heure* is a fixed expression meaning "prematurely"; here it seems to be a tongue-in-cheek reference to the idea that the bonesetter would be called a chiropractor if he were around today, but he was "ahead of his time", *avant l'heure*.
- *dut-il* means "even if, even though, be that as it may that the patient had to", and creates a contrast between the patient's cries and the hands determined to heal.